# Asyncronous Servlet do not serves multiple request

Tags: java

i have some problem with async request in java... Simply have following servlet:

```
public class Notifier extends HttpServlet{
public void service(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res){

final AsyncContext ctx = req.startAsync();`
...
}
```

I thoght, that this servlet serves thousand request (by few threed), but wen i test it by ajax only 6 request received on servlet side;

test code snippet is following:

```
for(i=0;i<5000;i++){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
```

}
    }

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/Notifier?mode=authorised&a="+i,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I have not idea why Notifier servlet does not serve all request which i send from browser...

Thank you in advance...

Comment: How do you verify that a request is received in the servlet?

Comment: System.out.println(request.getParameter("a"))

Comment: How do you test it? Are you sure that it's not a limit at the browser side?

Comment: I test it by ajax request. no limit at browser side. problem is at server side at line req.startAsync(); without this line server serves all incoming request...

Answer (score 0):

maybe it deals with the maximum length of the GET request? the information you can send has a maximum of 1024 characters? try it out with POST

Comment: only one parameter(number from 0 to 5000) send with get... problem is in req.startAsinc(); without req.startAsinc(); servlet serves all request.